Can a dual stack IPV4/IPV6 be bad for connection on a connection base game like call of duty
I have been with EE for a few months now and have been struggling with connection in game and streaming things to my TV.
My Question is could this be down to dual stacked IPv's 4/6

No. IPv4 and IPv6 are fundamentally different. You connect to either of the two, but never both and you can't just switch either. They're fundamentally different. You can see if you can connect using IPv4 only and then redo the test with IPv6 (this may be harder if the other end does not support IPv6. But games like Call of Duty should be connecting to a master server anyway.

What makes you think that it is related to this? Besides just guessing, what research have you done regarding the issues you're having? What are the symptoms of the problems you're experiencing? The only "details" you given us are "struggling with connection and streaming things to my TV". This isn't a lot of detail. Please describe your problems are clearly as you are able including the full content of any messages that you receive, and other details of your system and network.

Lets start by assuming everything is correctly configured:

Your ISP supports both IPv4 & IPv6
You are using a DNS server that can returning either.
The game you are playing supports connections over both.

It is possible that your ISP is shaping traffic differently (has different) shaping rules for each stack, I wouldn't expect that to affect gaming to much, as is unlikely your game is sending enough data to saturate your connection. However you might see if a difference if your connection is busy (you have some big downloads running concurrently). Before my ISP supported IPv6 I was tunneling 6over4 and was seeing better better performance using that vs direct IPv4 (I suspect the ISP didn't expect people to tunnel IPv6 so didn't have shaping rules in place).
If something is misconfigured on the IPv6 stack somewhere between you and the game server then all bets are off / it might help to disable IPv6.
Finally are you sure your ISP supports IPv6, it's possible you have a link local IPv6 address, but don't actually have a public address. I think it is unlikely that this would cause an issue, since you are probably only using IPv4 DNS, however if you are messing with IPv6 locally (Read: you have setup a local DNS server that support IPv6), then you should double check your ISP supports it.

@LPChip's comment should have been an answer, so copying it here.
No. IPv4 and IPv6 are fundamentally different. You connect to either of the two, but never both and you can't just switch either. They're fundamentally different. You can see if you can connect using IPv4 only and then redo the test with IPv6 (this may be harder if the other end does not support IPv6. But games like Call of Duty should be connecting to a master server anyway.


could this be down to dual stacked IPv's 4/6

Usually not because of dual-stacked connection in itself, no. Many games these days are written to support both IPv4 and IPv6, but even an IPv4-only game would only use IPv4 and wouldn't be bothered by the presence of IPv6.
(In theory it's not impossible for IPv4-only programs to accidentally request IPv6 addresses and then break upon receiving them, but that's rare, and considering that probably millions of users have IPv6 at home now, I'd expect such problems to be caught relatively quickly.)
What could be a problem is when the ISP offers dual-stack, but their IPv6 connectivity actually happens to be broken in some way, and nobody notices or complains because their web browsers just switch to IPv4 for everything (and if anybody notices, they can never get through to support staff who knows what "IPv6" is…) In such situations, differences between how programs handle fallback from one protocol to another could mean that web browsers fall back to IPv4 immediately, some apps take a few seconds, and some games just keep trying the non-working IPv6 forever.
Additionally – because IPv4-based Internet and IPv6-based Internet are actually two disjoint networks (sharing the physical connections but not the routing), it is possible and still quite common for them to have different paths to the same destination. Sometimes it's due to load-balancing (some packets take the path through carrier A, some take carrier B), but often ISPs literally do not bother to make all of their upstream peerings dual-stack, and so it could be that IPv4 traffic can take a very short path through a direct peering whereas IPv6 to the exact same destination needs to take the long way around through a carrier ISP or two.
